# How to prohibit line breaks between div elements when the container width is shorter than the sum of the widths of the children

Tags: html, css

I have a container div element and some children div elements.

```
<div>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
  <div>baz</div>
<div>
```

I want to horizontally list the children elements in a single line without line breaks. I read that I can use `white-space:nowrap` on the container element and/or `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` on the children. This works when the container's width is long enough.

However, I have a container whose width may become shorter than the sum of the widths of the children. The way mentioned above does not prohibit line breaks in such case. I still want to prohibit line breaks and force them to be on a single line, with the extra part of children being `hidden` if the container width is not enough. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```
#parent{
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

.child{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YAp6k/

Comment: This is mostly right but the child either needs an overflow:hidden or the width and height need to be removed because right now the text just runs on top of the other divs when it exceeds the length.

Comment: @fdsa It all depends what is in the child divs.  That information was not included in the question.  If it is text that needs to wrap then a simple `white-space: normal` should suffice.

Comment: That's a good point. I assumed that he wanted it one way but he really didn't specify

Comment: I have fixed width div elements as children, and do not want their shape to change in any way. Do I have to set `overflow:hidden` for the children as well?